Interacting with a webview when it may or may not be loaded
I have a Java class that loads content into a WebView. This WebView contains a JavaScript program that I need to query to, eg, populate lists of GUI components, call methods that return primitives, etc.
The problem for me is that WebViews can only be interacted with on the JavaFX application thread, and loading happens on a background thread. This means that the JS program loads ~500ms after my class is initialised, so for this period, my class is invalid and any method calls that query the JS program will return some sort of exception (eg, because the DOM object does not yet exist). However, I can't wait on it, because that locks the JavaFX application thread and loading never completes.
I want to be able to query the JS program in such a way that calling classes can get a handle on a future of an answer, but  any attempt I've made at this ends up deadlocking the JavaFX application thread.
In case it helps to demonstrate an answer, this is a minimal example of a similar class, that loads a CDN'ed JS text editor, and queries a variable defined once the page is loaded.
In this example, I want a way for classes interacting with WithWebView objects to be able to call getX in a "safe" way such that they (eventually) get the answer. I gather I should use CompletableFuture<?> here to do this, but I'm somehow not getting my head around how I can wait for the page to finish loading and still return a value in the future. The only "safe" way is the one shown below, where I add a callback to the stateProperty of the WebEngine's loadWorker.
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WithWebView {
    private WebView webView;

    WithWebView() {
        webView = new WebView();
        String content = """
        <html>
        <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds@1.35.1/src-min-noconflict/theme-chrome.min.js "></script>
        <script>
        x = "Answer"
        </script>
        
        </html>
        """;
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);
        // System.out.println(getX()); // this will throw an exception, because loading takes some time
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((v, o, n) -> {
            if (n == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                System.out.println(getX()); // this will work because I'm waiting on the loadworker to finish
            }
        });

    }

    Parent getParent() {
        return webView;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return (String)webView.getEngine().executeScript("x");
    }
}

with a simple application wrapper:
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WithWebView wwv = new WithWebView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(wwv.getParent(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}


This answer is adapted from this previous answer with some changes to the code and explanations added, as well as an alternative approach being shown (which may well be preferable).
To do this with a CompletableFuture, as specified in the question, the basic plan is as follows. Note though that you might not really need all the machinery of a completable future and its associated threading, as described later.

Create a CompletableFuture<String> (which will be completed by invoking the script on the web page when the web page completes loading).
Create an ObservableValue<Optional<String>> which will be empty until the page is loaded and then contain the results of invoking the script on the page.
Subscribe to changes in the observable value, completing the completable future with its value when a value is present.
Client code can then retrieve the completable future and apply functions or accept its value as needed.

Step 1 is straightforward: just construct the uncompleted CompletableFuture.
For step 2, we can take the state of the web engine's load worker, and map it to an Optional<String>. If the state is SUCCEEDED, return an optional with the value from the script, otherwise just return an empty value.
Here is a web view containing class that implements the first three steps:
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class WithWebView {
    private WebView webView;
    private CompletableFuture<String> pageLoadFuture;

    WithWebView() {
        webView = new WebView();

        // Step 1: create an uncompleted completable future:
        pageLoadFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

        String content = """
                <html>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds@1.35.1/src-min-noconflict/theme-chrome.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                x = "Answer"
                </script>
                </html>
                """;
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);

        // Step 2: create an observable value which contains an empty value
        // when the page is not loaded, and the result of calling the
        // javascript when the page has loaded:
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().map( state ->
            switch(state) {
                case SUCCEEDED -> Optional.of((String) webView.getEngine().executeScript("x"));
                default -> Optional.<String>empty();
            }
        )

        // and subscribe to changes in it, completing the future
        // when the value is present:

        .subscribe(x -> x.ifPresent(pageLoadFuture::complete));
    }

    Parent getParent() {
        return webView;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> getX() {
        return pageLoadFuture;
    }
}

For client code to use this, we can retrieve the CompletableFuture and use thenApply() to apply a function to it, or thenAccept() to just do something with it.
For example,
wwv.getX().thenApply(x -> "Javascript Variable: " + x);

will generate a new CompletableFuture with the concatenated strings, or
wwv.getX().thenAccept(System.out::println);

will print out the value when it is available.
Here's some example client code that does both:
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WithWebView wwv = new WithWebView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(wwv.getParent(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Querying the JavaScript variable x after page load
        wwv.getX().thenApply(x -> {
            return "Javascript variable: "+x ;
        }).thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

Threading
The functions passed to thenAccept() or thenApply() will be executed on the same thread as the completion of the previous stage. In this case, the initial completion happens in the listener to the state property of the web view's load worker, which is invoked on the FX Application Thread. Consequently everything else that happens to the result is also executed on the FX Application Thread.
If that is all that is needed, then the use of CompletableFuture and its associated machinery may be overkill. An alternative solution is outlined below.
No long-running processes should be performed on the FX Application Thread. So if processing the data from the web view takes any time, this should be performed asynchronously. The thenApplyAsync(...) and thenAcceptAsync(...) methods will do this, running the provided functions on a background thread.
The following modifications demonstrate this usage, mocking a long-running process with a sleep. If you try this on the FX Application Thread, the UI will become unresponsive:
//        wwv.getX().thenApply(x -> {
//            return "Javascript variable: "+x ;
//        }).thenAccept(System.out::println);

        wwv.getX().thenApplyAsync(x -> {
            // mimic long-running process:
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return "Javascript variable: " + x ;
        }).thenAccept(System.out::println);

Note that if any of the steps do run on a background thread, then the UI cannot be updated on that thread. Here is a version of the original client code which updates a label instead of printing to the console:
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WithWebView wwv = new WithWebView();
        Label label = new Label();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(wwv.getParent());
        root.setBottom(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Querying the JavaScript variable x after page load
        wwv.getX().thenApply(x -> {
            return "Javascript variable: "+x ;
        }).thenAccept(label::setText);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

However, if we try to do this when the processing step is in a background thread:
        wwv.getX().thenApplyAsync(x -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return "Javascript variable: " + x ;
        }).thenAccept(label::setText);

an IllegalStateException will be thrown, because the label's text will be set from a background thread. The solution to this is to use thenAcceptAsync(...) and specify the executor on which to execute the function. An Executor is simply a functional interface with a public void execute(Runnable) method. Since this is the same method signature as Platform.runLater(...) (which executes a Runnable on the FX Application Thread), we can just specify Platform::runLater as the executor:
        wwv.getX().thenApplyAsync(x -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return "Javascript variable: " + x ;
        }).thenAcceptAsync(label::setText, Platform::runLater);

Using JavaFX properties and values instead of completable future
In the original case, where none of the processing of the result needed to happen on a background thread, the use of CompletableFuture and its multithreading support is probably overkill. The code created an observable value which was updated when the value was available. If no background threading is needed, then this can be achieved simply by exposing the ObservableValue<String> and responding to changes in it in the client. The following demonstrates this approach.
package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WithWebView {
    private WebView webView;

    WithWebView() {
        webView = new WebView();
        String content = """
                <html>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds@1.35.1/src-min-noconflict/theme-chrome.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                x = "Answer"
                </script>
                </html>
                """;
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);

    }

    Parent getParent() {
        return webView;
    }

    public ObservableValue<String> xValue() {
        return webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().map(state ->
            switch(state) {
                case SUCCEEDED -> (String)webView.getEngine().executeScript("x");
                default -> null;
            }
        );
    }

    public final String getX() {
        return xValue().getValue();
    }
}

package com.example.demowebview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WithWebView wwv = new WithWebView();
        Label label = new Label();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(wwv.getParent());
        root.setBottom(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Querying the JavaScript variable x after page load

        wwv.xValue().subscribe(x -> {
            if (x != null) {
                label.setText("Javascript variable: " + x);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}


Thanks, very helpful. I'd ended up running into the JavaFX application thread issue, but didn't realise you could supply Platform::runLater as an exectutor.

Thanks again, some semi-painful refactoring later this has resolved a lot of very convoluted code and some race conditions where I was basically trying to reinvent the wheel. Much appreciated.
